# HighCharts unable to use data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to display graphs on my site.
http://www.highcharts.com/

On my graph div, I have created a data- attribute that must be used by the javascript to populate the graph.

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" data-mydata="{name: 'Test', data: [1,2,3,4,5]}"></div>
```

When I do this, and reference the data attribute in my javascript,

```
series: [
            $('#container').data("mydata")
        ]
```

no data is rendered on the graph (and no error - the empty graph renders). Here's a non-working example of what I am seeing. I even alert the data to see that it's there and valid.

http://jsfiddle.net/a30oap8h/1/

If I then copy and paste the data from the data- attribute and hard code it into the code,

```
series: [
            {name: 'Test', data: [1,2,3,4,5]}
        ]
```

it works fine.

How can I get this to work using the data- attribute?

Answer (score 0):

$('#container').data("mydata")  the expression will get a string , you should convert it to object . 
http://jsfiddle.net/kofijita/kpa4g1d3/1/

```js
$(function () {
var data = $('#container').data("mydata");
data = eval(data);
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
           
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [
         data
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto" data-mydata='{"name": "Test", "data": [1,2,3,4,5]}'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That example worked. But it seems now my data fails with the 'eval' statement. I've updated the sample with my data, and it's now failing. Can you see why? : http://jsfiddle.net/kpa4g1d3/2/

Comment: Note, this works when I use the data direly in the javascript - only when it's using the data attribute, it fails. I tried JSON.parse as well, but it told me about an invalid chat at index 2.

Comment: u should use a json string as the value for data-mydata like me,data-mydata='{"name": "Test", "data": [1,2,3,4,5]}'

Comment: Is that in the jquery code? Or should the data be passed in a different format (json)?

Comment: i mean that u should use json string in html in my example ;http://jsfiddle.net/kofijita/kpa4g1d3/3/   maybe this example is better for u